# Django Access to Foreign Key data to set a field default value

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have two models with their respective forms. One has a Foreign Key link to the other and from, here I would like to set some fields default data.

```
class Lexicon(models.Model):

    [...]

    case_sensitive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    invariant = models.NullBooleanField(default=False)
    diacritics = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    [...]

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "lexicon"
        ordering = ["filename"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.filename


class Lexeme(models.Model):

    lexicon = models.ForeignKey(Lexicon, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    case_sensitive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    diacritics = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    [...]

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "lexeme"
```

I would like the Lexeme model fields "case_sensitive" and "diacritics" to default from Lexicon. I suppose the forms may be a better place to do this.

Any idea ?

Comment: I can imagine that you could put some logic in model save method to check and make default these fields from Lexicon

Comment: To be more precise, I would like these fields to default from lexicon in the user interface, but the user still needs to be able to change them if he wants.

Comment: If you want to display them in forms you can set initial values there. Something like here e.g.: https://avilpage.com/2015/03/django-form-gotchas-dynamic-initial.html
In other cases it can be easy substituted in views or templates. As far as I get this question

Comment: Tried your link but can't get it to work, this is a ModelForm by the way !

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you only need to populate data from `Lexicon` to `Lexeme` model fields. You can override `get_form_kwargs` in your `FormView` as follows

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    lex_obj = Lexeme.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
    kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['initial']['case_sensitive'] = lex_obj.lexicon.case_sensitive
    kwargs['initial']['diacritics'] = lex_obj.lexicon.diacritics
    return kwargs
```

Is that what you want? I have not tested but, I have used similar thing on my project. Let me know if works or not.

Comment: The fact is, I want to use to populate the ModelForm that will create a lexeme. So lex_obj refers to nothing I believe. And it's **lex_obj.lexicon.case_sensitive** instead of _self.lex_obj.lexicon.case_sensitive_ right ?

Comment: Yes. You are right. I know you are trying to use `ModelForm`, but, for that modelForm to render, you have some view right? Using this way, you can send data to your `ModelForm`

Comment: Like alexxmagpie mentioned above ? Tried it, but can't get it to work, this defaults both of my fields to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the way to go. It was just basic initial setting of field, no need to touch to forms.py, models.py nor the html template.
I passed data to my form like this:

```
lexeme_form = LexemeForm(initial={'case_sensitive': lexicon.case_sensitive, 'diacritics': lexicon.diacritics})
```

Answer (score -1):

use **Ajax** at template to change the initial value of "case_sensitive" and "diacritics" when Lexicon changed, and abstract model can be used to reduce repeat lines :

```
class BaseLex(models.Model):
    case_sensitive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    diacritics = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Lexicon(BaseLex):
    # without `case_sensitive` and `diacritics' fields 
    ...

class Lexeme(BaseLex):
    # without `case_sensitive` and `diacritics' fields 
    lexicon = models.ForeignKey(Lexicon, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

Comment: That's not what I want right? I would like that with the creation of a lexeme, the values are taken from the lexicon.